# Vimeo Srt Jquery Plugin

Tags: jquery, vimeo

I am trying to add subtitles to a vimeo video using the Vimeo Srt Jquery Plugin found here

https://github.com/Yomguithereal/vimeo-srt

I can get subtitles to play fine using the template, but I want a drop down select to choose and change your subtitles as required. I have the below code, but it looks like once the subtitles are initialised it wont change. Anyone any suggestions?

```
<div id="container">
<iframe id="vimeoplayer" video="68038551" width="690px" height="422px" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/68038551?api=1&player_id=vimeoplayer" scrolling="no">      </iframe>
    </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.vimeo-srt.js"></script>
    <form class="pure-form pure-form-stacked">
<select name="subs" id="subs">
  <option selected="selected" value="0">Subtitles</option>
  <option value="EN">English</option>
  <option value="RU">Russian</option>
  <option value="TL">Tagalog</option>
  <option value="ZH">Chinese</option>
</select>
</form>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var $player =$("#vimeoplayer");
            $player.vimeoSrt({srt : 'vgroup_env_comp.EN.srt'});

            $( "#subs").change(function () {

                if ($("#subs").val() == "0") {
                    $player.vimeoSrt({srt :''});   
                } else {
                    var pathtofile= "mysubtitles." + $( "#subs" ).val() + ".srt";
                    $player.vimeoSrt({srt : pathtofile});
                }
            });
        });


    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that this plugin doesn't have any method to change the substitles, so it must be modified.
You can create a new method (for example just after "findSuitableStep") called "loadSrt", with this code:

```
,loadSrt: function (file) {
    var self = this;

    $.get(file, function (srt) {
        //Remove the current subtitles
        self._srt = [];

        //Set new subtitles
        self.parseSrt(srt);
    });
}
```

Then, you can call this function in this way:
`$player.data('plugin_vimeoSrt')('loadSrt', 'subtitles.srt');`

I didn't check the code, some bugs can be, but I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Oscar. I see where you are going with this, cant get it to work. Think its to do with the way the function is called. I get error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" when I call. I have tried various permutations (In new to jquery) but no joy so far

Comment: Yes, There is an error calling the function. You can try this: `$player.data('plugin_vimeoSrt').loadSrt('subtitles.srt');`